# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>

Tags: apache, deployment, apache-tomee

When i was trying to deploy my project, i got this error:

```
Sep 01, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Sun\Apache Tomee+\conf\Catalina\localhost\Workshop.xml
Sep 01, 2014 11:34:27 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: ------------------------- localhost -> /Workshop
Sep 01, 2014 11:34:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(F:\Web Design\wwwroot\Ali Farvardin\Farvardin Workshop\Workshop\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 01, 2014 11:34:28 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEClassLoaderEnricher validateJarFile
WARNING: jar 'F:\Web Design\wwwroot\Ali Farvardin\Farvardin Workshop\Workshop\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar' contains offending class: javax.persistence.Entity. It will be ignored.
Sep 01, 2014 11:34:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Workshop]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:547)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1496)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:368)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Workshop: null
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2062)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1099)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1054)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module Workshop: null
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:838)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:219)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2060)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1120)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:139)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:152)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AsynchronousInheritanceAnnotationFinder.<init>(AsynchronousInheritanceAnnotationFinder.java:43)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:114)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:830)
    ... 50 more

Sep 01, 2014 11:34:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor D:\Sun\Apache Tomee+\conf\Catalina\localhost\Workshop.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Workshop]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:547)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1496)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:368)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**My libraries:**

JSF2.2

Java EE 7 API Library

PrimeFaces 4.0

EclipsLink (JPA 2.1)

JDK 1.8

Apache Tomcat or TomEE

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <description>Farvardin Workshop</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/FarvardinWorkshop</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>    

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
       <param-value>none</param-value>
     </context-param>    

</web-app>
```

**context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Workshop"/>-->
<Context path="/Workshop">
  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/FarvardinWorkshop" password="123456" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FarvardinWorkshop" username="root"/>
  <Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container" type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

Web Server : Apache

Web Profile : TomEE+

Framework : JSF 2.2

IDE : Netbeans 8.0

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. My web server was Apache TomEE 1.6  that uses ASM4 and ASM4 only supports Java 7 bytecode. For Java 8, ASM5 is needed. After updating to Apache TomEE Plume 1.7 (that supports EclipseLink compared with Apache TomEE Plus), the problem was solved.

**Links that helped me:**

[TomEE - Unable to create annotation scanner for web module: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921889/tomee-unable-to-create-annotation-scanner-for-web-module-null)

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomee-users/201405.mbox/%3CCAGV8jqibfXFuvkJrE533zu16nOaLXhoR6u4F8VC1ottOs5ajOg@mail.gmail.com%3E

http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html

Unfortunately another error appeared : SEVERE: Unable to load Persistence Unit from EAR. (next post)